# Unexpected behavior of derived class using parent class member to call overridden member

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, overriding

I have a class derived from a parent class. It calls a member from the parent class. However a behaviour of the member need to be revised due to the functional requirement of the child class. I wrote the code in this way:

```
class parentClass
{
public:
    void memberA()
    {
        memberB();
    }
    void memberB()
    {
        behaviorParent;
    }
};

class childClass:public parentClass
{
public:
    void memberB()
    {
        behaviorChild;
    }
};

int main()
{
    child naughty;
    naughty.memberA();
}
```

I'm expecting a behaviorChild come as the result. However instead, the program gives me an behaviorParent rather than behaviorChild. Do you know why is that? And, how to fix it without replicating the code of parent member?

Comment: What is the `A()` method?

Comment: please insert real code, this won't compile

Comment: This is just an example. if compile is necessary, change memberB into cout will do. But I don't see if that help much on presenting the question so I didn't do it...

Comment: A() and B() have their own purpose. Original code is quite long. But here it only means that classParent and classChild share an exact A() but different B().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parentClass::memberB` is not declared `virtual`. The compiler therefore assumes, that the call to `memberB` from `parentClass::memberA` refers to `parentClass::memberB`.

To tell the compiler that the call to `memberB` should refer to a `memberB` defined in a derived class if such a function exists, declare `parentClass::memberB` as

```
virtual void memberB();
```

Comment: So if in parent class, memberB is defined as virtual, then even if I don't redefine memberA(because there is nothing changed in memberA for child class other than the changed behavior of called memberB, so I really don't want to rewrite the code), childClass::memberB will be called by memberA?

Comment: Yes; try it and you'll see.

Answer (score 0):

you dont have `child::A()` in the derived class. So it'll be the base version. If you want something else you need to override `child:A()` in derived class

Comment: Child::A() and Parent::A() share a same behavior, redefining will do nothing but repeating the code don't you think? Actually as Oswald suggested, I just need to use virtual member in classParent. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're using `memberA()` method from your base class. This method in base class cannot have any idea of what have you implemented in the child. That's why it still calls `memberB()` from base class.

If you don't want to change your base class code you will have to override `memberA()` method in your child class.

You can find an [example of overriding in C++ here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overriding#C.2B.2B).

Comment: A() for two classes have a same behavior. I don't see the reason of redefining it again. As Oswald suggested. I should have used virtual member in classParent.

Comment: I understood that you need to do this without modification of of parentclass' code.